# Watson is not accepting 3 digit numeric input

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, watson-dialog, watson

I am new to watson conversation and trying to create a chatbot for online shopping. So far every thing worked fine for me apart from payment step.

On the payment when I am trying to enter cvv code for credit card it is redirecting me back to start of that branch.

In the dialog for watson response for that step used following code:

```
{
  "output": {
    "text": "Ramdom cvv output to test the step."
  },
  "context": {
    "cvv": "<?input.text?>"
  }
}
```

But the moment I enter any 3 digits (in watson Try it out) it redirects me to start of that branch. I have tried with  and  but no luck.

I tried with @OneWordChoices:Yes decision as well with following, but no luck.

```
{
  "output": {
    "text": "Are You sure to proceed for payment"
  },
  "context": {
    "cvvpinIds": {
      "cvvpin 1": "123",
      "Cvvpin One": "123",
    },
    "checkoutStep": "cvvpin",
    "selectedcard": "@cvvpin"
  }
}
```

I want to enter 3 digit number for that step and validate input is 3 digit and numeric.

Appreciate any help.
Cheers,
Abhi

Comment: There is really not enough here to go on. Most likely reason is not passing back the context object. After that, you don't have a true node in your branch to prevent it falling back to root. See: https://sodoherty.com/2016/09/10/understanding-how-a-conversation-flows/

Comment: As a side topic. You should not be passing PCI to conversation. Instead at your application layer handle it. See "Message Shaping" at same blog.

Comment: Thanks Simon, Actually I do have a true node there which continue from link for prior step to this one.

Comment: Add your comment as the answer marked answered, if that was the solution.

Comment: Could this help to solve your problem? E.g. running the input through regular expression such as here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40864577/6779656